# A plugin by the name "Album\Segment" was not found in the plugin manager

Tags: zend-framework

I am following the zend 3 tutorial on how to create modules (they use the album blog as an example) [creating a blog](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/modules/)

However I ran into the following error when I created the module;

> A plugin by the name "Album\Segment" was not found in the plugin manager
>   Fatal error: Uncaught exception Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException'
>   with message 'A plugin by the name "Album\Segment" was not found in the plugin manager 
>   Zend\Router\RoutePluginManager' in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf-
>       tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zend-   servicemanager\src\AbstractPluginManager.php:131`

It appears that a plugin is missing. I am not the only one who has experienced this problem.

[lean438 raised the same problem at the zend forumn](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&p=265023)

Answer (score 6):

Put this line in `module.config.php` file in `album` module directory:

```
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
```

Answer (score 2):

just add following Code into module/Album/config/module.config.php

Following Is entire code File

```
namespace Album; 
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;
return [
'router' => [ 
    'routes' => [
        'album' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/album[/:action[/:id]]',
                'constraints' => [
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\AlbumController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],

 'view_manager' => [
    'template_path_stack' => [
        'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ],
],
];
```

Comment: This definitely fixes the issue, but I'm wondering why? A previous step explicitly removed one of the lines required to fix it...

`use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;`

Answer (score 2):

Just add
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
The other line does not appear to be needed to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using Laminas then, use below code in module.config.php file in album module directory

use Laminas\Router\Http\Segment;